# changing CRS in GeoPandas

Tags: geopandas, pyproj

I'm trying to change the CRS of a geopandas dataframe. The current CRS is:

```
Name: unknown
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- lon[east]: Longitude (degree)
- lat[north]: Latitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- undefined
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

When I try dfTrans.to_crs('epsg:4326') I get the following error:

```
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: cannot build geodeticCRS 4326: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: publication_date)
```

For a simple command in pyproj, pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326), I get the same error:

```
  File "pyproj/_crs.pyx", line 1738, in pyproj._crs._CRS.__init__
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: cannot build geodeticCRS 4326: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: publication_date)
```

I don't know enough to know what's going on, but it seems like there's an underlying function that calls a column that doesn't exist. Any ideas how to fix this or work around it?

Comment: These commands only give errors in PyCharm. Using the command line to run python, there is no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I got that same error when using Proj-5.x.  It seems that the 'publication_date' column is a Proj-6 or Proj-7 item (which both require SQLite.)